# Calculated Fields - InfoPath

Tags: 2013, infopath, calculated-column

I am trying to add a calculation to one of my fields in InfoPath, I know how to do this in Excel, but I can't quite figure it out in InfoPath.

This is how I would express the formula in excel:

```
=IF(A1*A2=0, 0, A1*A2)
```

> So cell A1 x cell A2, if A2 is 0 then display  A1

Answer (score 2):

There is no IF conditional formula in Infopath you have to use rules

- Go to field1 -> right click -> Rules
- Create a rule -> New "Action"
- Condition "number(field1) * number(field2) = 0"
- Run these Actions "Set Field Value"
- Select "field3" and set value 0
- Repeat above steps for field 2
- field 3 default value "number(field1)*number(field2)"

We were applied these steps in case of conditional value.

Answer (score -1):

Can use "Rules" to set value to field.

Ex: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-rules-f00de016-7b2d-4ef8-b168-26b7748c22a1